# Are PhD students allowed to extend their graduate studies to have a better chance at an academic job?

Tags: graduate-school

How long is this allowed for even after the student has completed graduation requirements?

Comment: I think this is very country dependent. No way it would fly in the UK, while within reason it would be fine at many universities in the US. No idea about other countries.

Comment: You may find the following question useful: [Should Ph.D. students interested with research remain as research assistant until they find a research position or just find any job?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42952/should-ph-d-students-interested-with-research-remain-as-research-assistant-unti)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the United States, there is a lot of opportunity for flexibility in scheduling graduation, assuming the faculty member has sufficient funding and motivation to keep the student around.

In most cases, however, the student would likely be served better not by delaying their graduation but instead by arranging for a transitional period as a postdoc with their same advisor.  In many cases, the cost of a postdoc is often not terribly different than a graduate student (higher salary is offset by lack of tuition), and there is typically little difficulty converting grant money from one to the other.

As a postdoc, however, there is no longer a question of graduation and thesis hanging over the former student's head, and they can be more free to focus instead on publication, networking, giving talks, and other things that will help to better position them for applying for academic positions.

Answer (score 7):

In general, what you are asking about is **not** possible, at least not in the manner in which you have written it.

At most schools in the US, once you have completed your graduate degree requirements, which include the defense, you are considered to have "graduated," at least as far as your "employment" with the university is concerned. Your contract typically terminates on the day you are said to have finished the graduation requirements. Therefore, postponing your graduation means delaying your defense.

What may instead be possible is to transition from a graduate student position into a temporary postdoctoral position within the group. It is often understood that this is simply a direct extension for the purposes of maintaining employment, rather than as a "new" position.

In Europe, the situation is quite different, as the model for "hiring" graduate students is typically contract-based. The willingness of your advisor to continue to employ you is then dependent on the availability of resources sufficient to extend the contract.

The **advisability** of such a move, as jakebeal indicates in his answer, is questionable, as it is becoming increasingly difficult to secure an academic position without experience beyond the graduate student level. That said, you're probably better off looking for a postdoctoral position and excelling there, rather than trying to just continue on your PhD work for an extended period of time.

Comment: In my experience in the US, after you defend you still need to submit your thesis to the library. This would allow a fair amount of flexibility without delaying the defense.

Comment: @StrongBad: At least at the schools I attended, stipend payments were cut off as of the day of the defense.

Comment: I was paid my stipend at MIT (which I think you attended) for 2 months after my defense while I waited for my post doc to start.

Answer (score 3):

The question is difficult, as it is likely to depend on your institution; however, rule of thumb (I have found) is that academic departments typically have a cap on the maximum number of years (~7yrs) you can be registered as a "graduate student," so if in principle, so long as you are below this max. years rule, you are allowed to extend your graduate education.

That being said, if you have already been studying for 5+ years, it is likely that if the department feels you've been successful they may begin to pressure your adviser to "get you out the door."

As for if it would provide better chances for an academic job, likely no. There are exceptions, one being on pursuing one of the NIH's new early-investigator awards. These awards are granted only to new graduates, and are designed to allow the recipient to "Skip" the post-doc phase of their career, and help set you up to apply to RO1 grants at an earlier age.

Another good reason to stick around is if you feel your work could be expanded on, and you don't see any post-doctoral advisers willing to allow you to do this. Some (though not all) post-doc advisers will treat you as laboratory equipment, and will stifle your independence (although slightly unethical, at least according to the journal Science, this does indeed happen) by prohibiting you  from exploring your own research interests. This carries the risk; however, of looking like you are not independent from your current adviser.

The best advice I've ever received concerning a similar situation is to discuss staying on as a post-doc for a short time at your current institution and apply for grant-funding of your own with your current adviser as a co-PI. If you are successful, you maybe able to leverage the department to list you as research faculty which would help you stick out from the crowd (including myself) of post-docs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the situation in mathematics in the states (at least for top 50 schools). The typical graduation time is 5 years. A student who is having a hard time, and doesn't have enough material to graduate (or get a post-doc) can stay for a sixth year, but this sometimes comes at a cost of having to teach more on the sixth year. Another way to proceed (for strong students) is to apply for post-doc in their fourth year, and then graduate in four years if the application is sucessful, or stay for the fifth year if the application is not sucessful. 
It is very rare to stay beyond the sixth year. Typically at this point, the student is allowed to stay affiliated with the university, but has found a job somewhere else, and is just hanging around to finish his thesis (but at this point it is clear that the student will not be applying for post-docs and just wants to have a thesis at the end of the phd journey).